# Can I change middle click to Pan?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, customization

I'd like to swap the controls for pan and orbit essentially so it's like AutoCAD where middle mouse click goes to pan and shift middle click is orbit. Where's the best place to suggest this as a feature add?

Comment: Are you trying to customize it yourself or learn where feature requests are posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this in *User Preferences > Keymap* (*Input* in 2.7x); just set the shortcuts for `view3d.rotate` and `view3d.move` accordingly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: I can't find this in Blender 2.8.

Comment: Never mind - found it - under Keymap